# Is it possible to write to multiple coils using pyModbusTCP library

Tags: python, tcp, modbus, modbus-tcp, pymodbus

There is a method from the documents that looks like `client.write_coils(1, [True]*8)`

My assumption is that this will write True 8 times because how do I supply a list of addresses? I want to supply a list of 8 modbuss address and assign them all True, for the sake of example. The alternate way is use the singular write_coil from a loop, but since write_coils exists in the docs I am assuming it is the better solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that the documentation for [`write_multiple_coils(addr, values)`](https://pymodbustcp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/package/class_ModbusClient.html#pyModbusTCP.client.ModbusClient.write_multiple_coils) is ambiguous.

You can look at the Modbus specification for [Write Multiple Coils](https://www.modbustools.com/modbus.html#function15) (function code 0x15) which says:

> Writes each coil in a sequence of coils to either ON or OFF.

So it might be helpful to think of the address as the starting address. So if your starting address is `1` and values is `[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]`, you'll write `True` to Coils 1 through 8. You could manually iterate through the values if you'd prefer, that's what the [example code](https://pymodbustcp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/client_write_coils.html#client-write-coils) does.

You can also look at the [source code for the function](https://github.com/sourceperl/pyModbusTCP/blob/cd22c569bf22080405835945bf813c7a75d95262/pyModbusTCP/client.py#L523):

One of the error checks also makes this plain:

```
if int(bits_addr) + len(bits_value) > 0x10000:
    raise ValueError('write after end of modbus address space')
```

If you try to write `[1,1,1]` to address `0x9999` you'll trigger this exception.